# Find an example of function

Tags: asymptotics

Find an example of a function $f$ such that satisfies:
$$\forall_{\varepsilon>0} \ f(n)=O(n^{1+\varepsilon})$$ but not $$f(n)=O(n)$$

I had been thinking about it for an hour and still can't find it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try multiplying two functions from different "growth classes".

Comment: Related: can you find a function which is $O(n^{\varepsilon})$ for all positive $\varepsilon$ but is not $O(1)$?

Comment: I was trying to approach this way, but failed.

Comment: Well, what were you trying?

Comment: Like WimC said I was trying to approach. For example $n^{1/n}=O(n^{\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon$, unfortunately it's also $O(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\log n = O(n^{\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Try to prove it, if necessary :)

Comment: I can see now, the answer is $f(n)=n^{1+\log n}$ it was simpler than I thought.

Comment: @xan, that function is not $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: $n\log n$ the solution is

Comment: @xan, there you go :)